# prevent checking same item from multiple checkedlistbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

If i have 2 checkedlistbox(s), each has same items, example : apple, banana. How can I prevent user from checking same item from both checkedlistbox(s). Case : user cannot check apple and apple (from checkedlistbox1 and checkedlistbox2). Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you the code which checks both the checkboxlist on button's click for "checking same item from both checkedlistbox are checked or not"

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) = True And CheckedListBox2.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
            MsgBox("checking same item from both checkedlistbox are not allowed")
        End If
    Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your help sir. i was just wandering in other sites for a solution, and i think your solution is more simple than what i have right now.. `If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains("Apple") And CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains("Apple") Then
            Dim msgc1 = "Dont choose same item from AVOID and MUST list"
            MsgBox(msgc1)
        Else`